# Dynamic content adding extra code to my email

Tags: content, marketing-cloud, dynamic

I'm trying to create an email using Templates with Dynamic content but have issues in Hotmail. Exact Target is adding ALL this extra code (I found this viewing source from Hotmail):

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bordercolor="" width="100%" bgcolor="">                               
   <tr>
     <td valign="top" align="center"><p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" align="center">
        <table  width="100%" bgcolor="#ff33ff" border="0" bordercolor="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px">
```

Which is totally unnecessary and is adding space to the image in Hotmail. How can I stop this from happening? Thanks

[image: Hotmail screengrab]

Comment: Is this in sny way related to products or software ubder the salesforce umbrella ? Else you'll have more luck over at stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, this is a question about Exact Target.

Answer (score 2):

When extra space is added below an image in Hotmail it's usually due to the image missing the display:block CSS property.

```
<img alt="Description" src="image.jpg" height="10" width="10"
style="display:block;">
```

Treating the image as a block level element should clear up the spacing. So long as you don't have any padding applied to the content area you should be fine.

If you want to avoid the HTML code added by ET, you can use an HTML Only content area.